# Not able to fix the play and pause button in mediacontroller video view

Tags: javascript, java, android, python, json

I am following [this](https://github.com/brucetoo/VideoControllerView) 
for the mediacontroller video view.

But when I import this and run in android studio, the play and pause button doesn't seem to be working. I tried a lot to figure it out but hasn't really got the luck. Did anyone had a similar issue before, how to fix it? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

I think I should have code like this for play and pause using onclicklistner. But I haven't got the idea where do I integrate it on the above link provided.

```
bottom_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(isPlaying()){

                    mMediaPlayer.pause();
                    bottom_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_48dp);

                }

                else{
                    mMediaPlayer.start();

                    bottom_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_play);

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Maybe there's some logic that you are not checking thoroughly for errors before the play/pause button logic?